# DDD: Where persist non domain data?

Tags: domain-driven-design, persistence, external

My app calls an external billing api and receives back an external id that must be sent to a second external service to check billing confirmation. The external id is only used in that moment and have no meaning for my domain. Where the best place to store that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you want to persist this information tells me that this billing process happens as a sequence of asynchronous operations or otherwise you wouldn't even need to persist the initial billing request id.

You will often find a process manager or a saga behind the orchestration of such process and those usually have a persitent state of their own. This is where I'd store that information.

Comment: Understood but what should I do when I have an external id (ex. customer external id) that must be used in every billing request?

Comment: @DavidDuarte Well if you model a Customer in the Billing bounded context you could store it there. If your sub-domain is not large enough to have it's own context then I guess that to be pragmatic you could just put it on your Customer and call it a day (how much harm will it do?). You could also implement a specialized service (outside of the domain) which is leveraged by the application layer and that allows to store/retreive those customer ids.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that integration with external systems is typically represented and modeled by two objects.  One in your Problem Domain (PD) that represents the external system, and an additional one outside the PD that represents the interface to the *actual* external system.  That external one is often organized in what might be called "System Interaction" (SI), and in many cases really is a library or interface provided by the manufacturer or 3rd party.

In your case, I would maintain the external id (if required) in that SI object and have the SI object send a message on for confirmation.

The PD and matching SI object typically share a "business" oriented interface, allowing the SI object to be developed independently.  It is common for the PD to access the SI object indirectly after is has been created by a factory based on some configuration information.